# jQuery - clearInterval seems not to work

Tags: jquery, if-statement, intervals, clearinterval

Long story short: If the interval count exceeds 5 the code should clear the interval, stopping it from executing the function every second. But this doesn't seem to work.

**HTML**

```
<div id='feedback'></div>
```

**JavaScript / jQuery**

```
window.intervalcount = 0;

var interval = setInterval(function () {
    intervalcount += 1;
    $("#feedback").text(intervalcount);
}, 1000);

if(intervalcount > 5) {
    clearInterval(interval);
}
```

But I can't seem to find the issue...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So currently, your code is going to run something like this order:

```
window.intervalcount = 0;

// Interval is defined here
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    intervalcount += 1;
    $("#feedback").text(intervalcount);
}, 1000);

// will be 0 still
if(intervalcount > 5) {
    clearInterval(interval);
}

// 1 second after the interval is defined:
    intervalcount += 1; // now equals 1
    $("#feedback").text(intervalcount);

// 2 seconds after defined:

    intervalcount += 1; // now equals 2
    $("#feedback").text(intervalcount);

// etc, forever
```

Placing the:

```
if(intervalcount > 5) {
    clearInterval(interval);
}
```

inside the interval's function will perform your desired behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You need the `if` inside the callback itself like

```
window.intervalcount = 0;

var interval = setInterval(function () {
    intervalcount += 1;
    $("#feedback").text(intervalcount);
    if(intervalcount > 5) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 1000);
```

This is because your code will not execute in a sequential manner. Rather, that `if` will execute before any of the intervals execute because they are executed *later*

Comment: This is because the original check for intervalcount only executed once, by putting that check inside of the callback to setInterval it will execute every time the interval is called.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to execute the `clearInterval()` immediately after setting it. That happens ***before*** any seconds have elapsed. First you set the interval, then you check if any have elapsed (they haven't) then five seconds later it **would** be time to clear the interval — but by then it's already run.

Perhaps you meant to check ***during*** the execution each time?

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    if(intervalcount > 5) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    } else {
        intervalcount += 1;
        $("#feedback").text(intervalcount);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: "You're executing the clearInterval() immediately after setting it" - actually not executing it at all, because `intervalCount` is `0` when the `if` statement is executed.